# How to configure nginx, gunicorn to run 2 django servers with different domain names

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have DjangoServer1 and DjangoServer2 running a virtualenv, where gunicorn is installed. nginx is installed under user in Ubuntu.

I make DjangoServer1 running under nginx, gunicorn.

Server IP: 12.12.12.12

Web site domain for DjangoServer1 is mydomain1.com

Web site domain for DjangoServer2 is mydomain2.com

This is nginx server config for DjangoServer1.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/DjangoServer1

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
            root /home/user/develop/DjangoServer1;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/develop/DjangoServer1/DjangoServer1.sock;
    }
}
```

I start the DjangoServer1:

1) Under virtualenv, run gunicorn command to start DjangoServer1

gunicorn --daemon --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/develop/DjangoServer1/DjangoServer1.sock DjangoServer1.wsgi

2) Then, run:

sudo service nginx restart

3) In router, I portforward port 80, 8000, to server 12.12.12.12

4) In browser, enter: 12.12.12.12. DjangoServer1 works. Enter: mydomain1.com, DjangoServer1 works.

Now, I want to run DjangoServer2 under same server: 12.12.12.12

Question: How to configure DjangoServer1 and DjangoServer2 to different port?

How to run gunicorn command to use different port? Following command uses port 8000? Why?

gunicorn --daemon --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/develop/DjangoServer1/DjangoServer1.sock DjangoServer1.wsgi

How to configure nginx file?

Comment: Can you try this `gunicorn --daemon --workers 3 --bind :8080 DjangoServer1.wsgi`?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I stoped nginx, and did:  gunicorn --daemon --workers 3 --bind :8080 loivideo.wsgi. localhost:8080 works. 12.12.12.12:8080 not work (should not work). Then, what should I do to /etc//etc/nginx/sites-available/DjangoServer1, so that mydomain1.com work? How to make mydomain2.com work?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Gunicorn command to run the servers on the specified port.

`gunicorn --daemon --workers 3 --bind :8080 DjangoServer1.wsgi`

Now change your NGINX conf file to forward it to the Application Server.

```
upstream django-server-1 {
    server 0.0.0.0:8080;
}


server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
            root /home/user/develop/DjangoServer1;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://django-server-1;
            proxy_next_upstream off;
    }
}
```

Restart your NGINX service.

This will forward all the requests coming to `80` port to your application server `DjangoServer1`.

If you explicitly want to forward requests coming to `8080` to your application server, change the `server` block in the NGINX configuration or have a new server block with your rules.

Comment: Thank you. I will try. Where to specify 'mydomain1.com'? I watched this youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tO2N0LLVZjI. In the video, domain name is in the config.

Comment: you can change `server_name` to domain name. check this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: I tested DjangoServer1 work under 'mydomain1.com'. To make DjangoServer2 to work under 'mydomain2.com' is to add another server section under same config: /etc/nginx/sites-available/DjangoServer1 or to add another config: /etc/nginx/sites-available/DjangoServer2?

Comment: Follow the steps to run your `DjangoServer2` on a different port. Once done, in the same NGINX conf add one more new `upstream` block and `server` block. specify the rules for your second server.

Comment: It worked for 2 domains 2 servers. Also, it eliminated hard coded directories in the configure file. thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.